# find rows that contains value which are not found in another list

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

bucket_file_extensions_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "bucket_file_extensions":
        [["NoExt", "NoExt", "json"], 
         ["log.gz"], 
         ["log.gz"],
         ["yml", "yml", "my-file.yaml"], 
         ["bucket.blah", "json"]]
})

extension_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "non_data_extenions":
        ["NoExt", "json", "gz", "yml", "yaml"]
})

extensions_as_tuple = tuple(extension_df.non_data_extenions.unique())

result = bucket_file_extensions_df.bucket_file_extensions.apply(
    lambda str_list: any(s.endswith(extensions_as_tuple) for s in str_list))

print(result)
```

Current Output:

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
Name: bucket_file_extensions, dtype: bool
```

the returned value should be 4 true and 1 false. the last row should return false

Comment: Why the first is True while the last is False?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are trying to do is...

```
["NoExt", "NoExt", "json"] match to ['NoExt', 'json', 'gz', 'yml', 'yaml']
["log.gz"] match to ['NoExt', 'json', 'gz', 'yml', 'yaml']
["log.gz"] match to ['NoExt', 'json', 'gz', 'yml', 'yaml']
["yml", "yml", "my-file.yaml"] match to ['NoExt', 'json', 'gz', 'yml', 'yaml']
["bucket.blah", "json"] match to ['NoExt', 'json', 'gz', 'yml', 'yaml']
```

`[True, True, True, True, False]`

thus:

```
import os

import pandas as pd

bucket_file_extensions_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "bucket_file_extensions":
        [["NoExt", "NoExt", "json"],
         ["log.gz"],
         ["log.gz"],
         ["yml", "yml", "my-file.yaml"],
         ["bucket.blah", "json"]]
})

extension_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "non_data_extenions":
        ["NoExt", "json", "gz", "yml", "yaml"]
})


def check_extensions(row):
    extension = []
    for item in row:
        root, ext = os.path.splitext(item)
        if ext:
            # Strip the "." character from the extension
            extension.append(ext[1:])
        else:
            # No extension part exists
            extension.append(root)
    for ext in extension:
        if ext not in extension_df["non_data_extenions"].values:
            return False
    return True


result = bucket_file_extensions_df["bucket_file_extensions"]\
    .apply(check_extensions)
print(list(result))
```

Output:

```
[True, True, True, True, False]
```